# xls Excel Set max number of bars in bar chart

Tags: excel

My bar chart has a max of 8 bars:
[image]

For my X-Axis I have marked more years:
[image]

Unfortunatly my bar chart only shows 8 bars. When I leave 2004 out, my chart starts at 2006 and includes 2020.

That means that there is some kind of setup for 8 bars.
I have not found anything usefull in the Axis options.
When I tried to create the chart form the scratch it was not limited to 8. Unfortunatly I have almost one hunderd of this charts, so I would like to avoid building them new.

Please let me know if anyone knows how to chage that limitation of bars.

Comment: The number of bars is not limited to 8 when I create a clustered bar chart. See screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4nQa.png). Might be a problem in your specific excel version? Try to create a completely new bar chart including all your data.

Comment: As mentioned, when I create a new chart it is not limited. But I have hundreds of charts so I would rather find the setting.